# javafx tableview sort filter issue

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I have a javafx table view with several cells. Sorting is enabled. Now I have a cell with 2 strings in it, but the sort filters on both of the strings in that cell in asc/desc.

I would like to make it so that the filter only applies to the first string in the cell, so it ignores string 2.

This is because my sorting gets messaged up because there are two different variables in the cell, of which the second one is not needed for the sort, but the first one is.  But now the sorting isn't correct because it takes the second string as well.

Is this possible? Or do I have to make it two seperate cells?

Answer (score 0):

Just set a comparator on the column. Assuming the item type of the column is a string (you can modify it appropriately if this is not the case):

```
myColumn.setComparator(Comparator.comparing(s -> {
    int index = s.indexOf(" ");
    if (index == -1) return s ;
    return s.substring(0, index);
}));
```

Comment: Thank you, but s doesn't seem to contain anything :O It has no indexOf nor substring D:

Comment: @Raflesia Sorry, what do you mean? I said assuming it's a string, so `s` is a `String`. Of course `String` has `indexOf` and `substring` methods.